# Matlab indexing and bounds

Tags: matlab, bounds

I get the following error when I try to run this code "Attempted to access id(90); index out of bounds because numel(id)=89.Error in Untitled66 (line 26) person = find(id(fileNum)==ids);" Can someone help me spot the error?

```
% File Names reading and label generation 

dataFolder= 'allcontent/';
fileNames = dir([dataFolder 'c*.*']);

lbl = sscanf(cat(1,fileNames.name)','co2%c%d.rd_%d.mat');
status = lbl(1:3:end);
id = lbl(2:3:end);
ids = unique(id);
trial = lbl(3:3:end);

%% File reading and Data Generation 


%data = 256*channel*trial*stimulus*id
trData = zeros(256,64,10,3,20,'single');
label = zeros(10,3,20,'single');
trials = ones(3,20);

for fileNum = 1:numel(fileNames)

fin = fopen([dataFolder fileNames(fileNum).name]);
for i=1:4
line= fgetl(fin);
end
a= sscanf(line,'%S%d  %s , trial %d');
stimulus = (3-numel(a));

person = find(id(fileNum)==ids);
trialNum = trials(stimulus, person);
label (trialNum, stimulus, person) = status(fileNum);
fprintf('%d %d %d\n', person,trialNum, stimulus);

for ch=1: 64
fgetl(fin);
curData = textscan(fin,'%d %s %d %f');
trData(:,ch,trialNum,stimulus,person) = curData{4};
end 
trials(stimulus,person) = trials(stimulus,person)+1;
fclose(fin);
end
```

Comment: What about the error message isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

`id = lbl(2:3:end)` is not as long as `numel(fileNames)`. Looking at your code it's impossible to say how long `fileName` or `id` is (but error msg says id is 89 long), since you pick `fileNames` from from a directory with condition `c*. *` while you choose `id` as some subset from the results of `lbl`... Phew... It's messi. But again, there's nothing clear about the lengths being the same. What **is** clear from error msg is that `fileName` is longer than `id`